# What is correct way to feed a css style rule as a parameter in a Javascript function?

Tags: javascript, css, parameters, functional-programming, html5-canvas

What is the correct way to style an HTML canvas element via a function that takes any style rule and value as parameters? Yes I know a direct Javascript approach would work. The setCSS() function is a testbed for a version 2 setCSS() function that is intended to set multiple css styles by utilizing an array of objects (key, values) as parameters such that each object represents a single CSS property. Here is what I have that is not working:

```
    function init() {
        'use strict';
        let can = document.getElementById('canvas');
        let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        resizeBlock(can, 50, 50);
 // Tried both forms individually by commenting out other function
        setCSS(can, 'borderWidth', '20px');// not working
        setCSS(can, 'borderWidth', '20');// not working
    }

    function setCSS(element, rule, value) {
        element.style.rule = value;
        return element; // should element return or not?
    }
```

Comment: `window.onload = init;` without parenthesis.

Comment: In you example: `window.onload = init();` is the same as: `window.onload = undefined` because the execution of `init` yields `undefined` (doesn't return anything). Instead you should not execute the function, just pass a reference to it so it can be called when the window loads.

Comment: even if you follow the upper examples, it wont work as window.onload is overriden by your second function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pure JavaScript equivalent to jQuery's $.ready() how to call a function when the page/dom is ready for it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9899372/pure-javascript-equivalent-to-jquerys-ready-how-to-call-a-function-when-the)

Comment: @Jonasw The functions are the same, OP is just asking why the second one works and the first not. He didn't mean to have two load events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`init` is the function, `init()` is the result of calling the function.

So this would work:

```
window.onload = init;
```

Also you may want to put it after defining the `init()` function.

```
function init() { ...snip... }
window.onload = init;
```

Comment: Not necessarly after defining the function. Read about **variable hoisting**.